# ObjectBox build.gradle

Tags: java, gradle, objectbox

Trying out to use ObjectBox as java desktop database. However after following the documentation on the web site https://docs.objectbox.io/java-desktop-apps its not working. No MyObjectBox found error.
I am using eclipse ide Version: 2020-09 (4.17.0), Gradle: gradle-6.7.1
ObjectBox seems not creating the model automatically after build (no model folder generated). I have created the class using the Entity annotation, build the project eclipse, nothing happens. Anyone any ideas?
Works in android but not desktop. As i am not familiar with gradle project in eclipse. the following is the build file

```
buildscript {
    ext.objectboxVersion = '2.8.1'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.objectbox:objectbox-gradle-plugin:$objectboxVersion"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'io.objectbox'

targetCompatibility = '1.8'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'


repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    
    implementation "io.objectbox:objectbox-linux:$objectboxVersion"
    implementation "io.objectbox:objectbox-macos:$objectboxVersion"
    implementation "io.objectbox:objectbox-windows:$objectboxVersion"
}
apply plugin: 'io.objectbox'

dependencies {
    implementation "io.objectbox:objectbox-java:$objectboxVersion"
    annotationProcessor "io.objectbox:objectbox-processor:$objectboxVersion"
}

apply plugin: 'io.objectbox'
```

Comment: Well, seem no one is answering.... i switched to use intelliJ idea.... the get start documentation on the web site https://docs.objectbox.io/java-desktop-apps works. Just need to revalidate cache and restart... probably eclipse is still caching the gradle things....

Answer (score 0):

Doing `apply plugin: 'io.objectbox'` three times does not look good. Once is enough. Please check the [ObjectBox Java examples](https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-examples) for a working setup. In your case have a closer look at the [java-main example](https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-examples/tree/main/java-main) for standalone Java applications.

This is the basic structure with `...` where I left out the details (check the full build.gradle file from the example):

```
buildscript {
...
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

targetCompatibility = '1.8'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

mainClassName = "io.objectbox.example.Main"

dependencies {
...
}

// Apply plugin after dependencies block so they are not overwritten.
apply plugin: 'io.objectbox'
```

Maybe checkout the example and start from there?

Comment: problem seems to be eclipse is not getting the ObjectBox auto generated classes,while intelliJ is set to get that automatically without further setting. Added sourceSets { main {  java {  srcDirs += ["src/build/generated/sources"]  } } } to build.gradle, but not working unfortunately.

Comment: There is a note about using Eclipse on the Java Desktop Apps docs page: https://docs.objectbox.io/java-desktop-apps#desktop-project-setup It reads: "For Eclipse see the [Buildship](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.buildship) project and [Getting Started](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGradle/article.html) article."